# How to answer to a potential employer about the reason for leaving

Tags: interviewing, work-environment

I left my work due to the toxic environment and pay was less than my last job. When I started my job I was told by the outsourced recruiter that in due time 3-6 months I will get a price match of my last job but it didn't happen as I bought that up with my line manager and the team environment was too toxic so I left as things weren't getting restored and mentally I was very disturbed.

Now a potential client wants to interview me and I do not want to sound like a job hopper who left a job just because of the toxic environment. It was more than that.

How can I say why I left work without sounding bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I say why I left work without sounding bad?

Just be honest with the potential client.  State all of the same reasons you gave in your question.

At the same time, you need to make sure that you research your next opportunity as best as you can to prevent ending up in a similar situation.  Any offers for pay/raises/incentives...etc need to be written into your contract rather than verbally mentioned to you.  Don't accept any offers unless you have done your due diligence in researching the company environment and all of your terms have been met ( in writing ).

Answer (score 2):

Be honest but try to phrase it positively. For example if the environment was toxic you can describe it in terms of how that affected your performance and general wellbeing. If the pay was too low you can say the financial pressure was making it difficult for everyone to concentrate on their work or feel valued.